# VB.net - Openfilepicker does not work in windows mobile 10 app

Tags: vb.net, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I'm developing a Windows 10 UWP and this piece of code :

```
Dim wopk As FileOpenPicker = New FileOpenPicker
With wopk
 .ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List
 .SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary
 .FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt")
 dim wfile = Await .PickSingleFileAsync()
End with
```

crash on my Lumia 535 (Windows mobile 10) without error message (both debug and runtime mode).

Appears the splash screen and still hang.

On desktop everything works fine.

In package manifest Declarations, I defined for File Open/Save Picker the ".txt" extension.

The project has as target "Windows 10" and as version "Build 10586".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is something that i have quickly written up, it should allow you to access `openfilepicker`
 It's not complete, however it should lead you in the right direction.

```
Imports Windows.Storage.Pickers
Public NotInheritable Class MainPage
Inherits Page

Private Async Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button.Click
    Dim openfilepicker = New FileOpenPicker
    openfilepicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary
    openfilepicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt")
    openfilepicker.CommitButtonText = "Open"

    Dim Textfile = Await openfilepicker.PickSingleFileAsync()
    If Textfile IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim SelectedTextFile = Await Textfile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite)
        'Write your code here using SelectedTextFile as the source for the async.
    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

If you have any problems i will do my best to help you out, however from what your question has stated, this should be more than enough.

Happy Coding!

Comment: I tried, but doesn't change. I have a strange effect : As I said instead of appear the openfilepicker, appear the splash screen, but if I click on Home button at bottom, the openfilepicker appear. Anyway at that point, whatever I select, do nothing.

Comment: When i use the windows phone emulator, it has no problem, maybe its your phone? try using the emulator and see if it works.

Comment: Could be. I will try using an emulator. Thank you.

Comment: no problem, if it works on the emulator for windows 10 mobile, back up your phones data and reformat it

Comment: I'm preparing a new pc because my pc cannot run the emulator. I will inform you .... Thank you.

Comment: I tried using an emulator and it works. I will try using another phone or reformatting my phone. Anyway your suggestion was correct. Thank you.

Comment: @Fritz not problem at all, happy to help, please mark the question as correct so the next person with the same problem can have the same help :) happy coding!

Comment: I am having the same problem (Nokia 735). I think the problem is for ARM-Based mobiles, which were upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. The emulators in VS2015 are x86-based.

Comment: change the emulator to ARM and see what happens

Comment: In VS2015 for ARM there are no emulators shown? Only "Device" is the option.

Comment: Check the following MSDN link for a discussion about the same issue (somehow it is in SQL Server forums): https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/13002ba6-6e59-47b8-a746-c05525953c5a/uwpfileopenpicker-bugs-in-win-10-mobile-when-not-debugging?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: you should be able to changethe cpu release type from memory i think